# understanding of vector and point

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I just have some confusions about basic understandings in vectors and points. For example, if $$\alpha(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$$ is a parametrized curve from $I$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$, then for a specific point $t_0 \in I$ ,  $\alpha(t_0)$ represents a vector or a point in $\mathbb{R^3}$ ? Why? I think $\alpha(t_0)$ is a point on $\mathbb{R^3}$, but I saw $\alpha(t_0)$ described as a position vector in Do Carmo's book. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are given a coordinate system in $R^3$, there exist a "one to one correspondence" between the set of all points in $R^3$ and the set of three dimensional vectors.  So we can interpret the $\alpha(t)= (x(t), y(t), z(t))$, for each t, to be either a point or the vector that, if we were to have its base at (0, 0, 0) would have its tip at the point (x(t), y(t), z(t)).

I am not saying that points and vector *are* the same thing!  For example, given the vector (x, y, z), which would represent the vector with end at (0, 0, 0) and tip at the point (x, y, z), we can [b]move[/b] that vector so that its end is at (a, b, c) and its tip is at (a+ x, b+ y, c+ z) but it is the same vector.  You can move vectors but you can't move points.

(Some texts use  for vectors specifically to distinguish vectors from points (x, y, z).)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that some things are essentially the same in mathematics -- *isomorphic* is the term of art.

This is also the case with vectors and points in Euclidean space. In particular, if we always take the position vector (i.e., those originating at the origin of coordinates) as the representative of each equivalence class of vectors, then there is an isomorphism between the points and vectors of that space, so that we may regard them as essentially the same thing.

How we think of them in a particular case would depend on which is more convenient for the problem at hand.

By the way, note that there is a difference between a curve and its trace.